# How to access python django dev server started in AWS Cloud9

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS. I created a test environments with AWS Cloud9, and a django project. When I start djangos dev server, is it possible to access it, from Cloud9 IDE preview or from the internet?

thanx for your help in advance,

strophi

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
python manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT
```

This will automatically set the correct details for you from the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` and then access from anywhere using the public IP, something like XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080

*Make sure the port is not blocked